# iOS: SQLCipher & SQLite performance?

Tags: ios, performance, sqlite, sqlcipher

I want to use SQLCipher to encrypt the database but i'm not sure about the performance.

How many percent of performance have to be sacrificed if i switch to use SQLCipher instead of using SQLite?

My database have around 4 tables , 10.000 records per each.
I use select with order queries the most.

Comment: Why don't you just write a test yourself with gibberish data?

Comment: I have never use SQLcipher before, so i don't want to waste time to install, convert database and mesure the performance.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt this: https://github.com/sqlcipher/SQLCipherSpeed

Answer (score 0):

For small databases, performance will be close, with the notable exception of the key derivation delay when the database is first opened (which is deliberately slow). Look at this for details on how to optimize performance, and make sure you adhere to all the recommendations there:

https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-performance/14

To get exact numbers on the performance you would need to convert your application and measure the impact. PRAGMA cipher_profile can help you identity hot-spots by logging time required to execute individual statements.